# How to make outputs of models which are not in broom tidy in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, broom

I have been trying to make the output of a `wfe` model as tidy so I can easily incorporate it into ggplot and etc. This is a problem I've had with other packages and statistical models which are not included in broom.

So let's say I create a dataset like this:  (taken from `wfe`'s file):

```
library (wfe)
        ## generate panel data with number of units = N, number of time = Time
    N <- 10 # number of distinct units
    Time <- 15 # number of distinct time
    
    ## treatment effect
    beta <- 1
    
    ## generate treatment variable
    treat <- matrix(rbinom(N*Time, size = 1, 0.25), ncol = N)
    ## make sure at least one observation is treated for each unit
    while ((sum(apply(treat, 2, mean) == 0) > 0) | (sum(apply(treat, 2, mean) == 1) > 0) |
           (sum(apply(treat, 1, mean) == 0) > 0) | (sum(apply(treat, 1, mean) == 1) > 0)) {
      treat <- matrix(rbinom(N*Time, size = 1, 0.25), ncol = N)
    }
    treat.vec <- c(treat)
    
    ## unit fixed effects
    alphai <- rnorm(N, mean = apply(treat, 2, mean))
        ## geneate two random covariates
    x1 <- matrix(rnorm(N*Time, 0.5,1), ncol=N)
    x2 <- matrix(rbeta(N*Time, 5,1), ncol=N)
    x1.vec <- c(x1)
    x2.vec <- c(x2)
    ## generate outcome variable
    y <- matrix(NA, ncol = N, nrow = Time)
    for (i in 1:N) {
      y[, i] <- alphai[i] + treat[, i] + x1[,i] + x2[,i] + rnorm(Time)
    }
    y.vec <- c(y)
    
    ## generate unit and time index
    unit.index <- rep(1:N, each = Time)
    time.index <- rep(1:Time, N)
    
    Data.obs <- as.data.frame(cbind(y.vec, treat.vec, unit.index, time.index, x1.vec, x2.vec))
    colnames(Data.obs) <- c("y", "tr", "unit", "time", "x1", "x2")
```

Now I run a model from the function wfe (again, code from the package's help file):

```
    mod.did <- wfe(y~ tr+x1+x2, data = Data.obs, treat = "tr",
               unit.index = "unit", time.index = "time", method = "unit",
               qoi = "ate", estimator ="did", hetero.se=TRUE, auto.se=TRUE,
               White = TRUE, White.alpha = 0.05, verbose = TRUE)

## summarize the results
summary(mod.did)
```

My question is how to turn this output into a tidy object I could plot.

If I call `tidy(mod.did)` I get the following error:

```
Error: No tidy method for objects of class wfedid
```

Which I understand, but I am unsure as to how to solve. I tried mapping the individual parameters (coefficient, se, etc.) into a new list object but that did not work, so I hope that someone here knows of a more systematic way of doing this.
In case it helps, here's a dput of the output: https://pastebin.com/HTkKEUUQ

Thanks!

Comment: disclaimer - I have not yet used the wfe package! Usually, most statistical packages will come with their predict method(s). Meaning when you use `predict(model)` you will get an object which will contain the data you need for plotting.

Comment: Like @tjebo I am also not familar with the wfe package.  providing the output from `dput(mod.did)` would help the likes of him and me to help you.  My suggestion would be to write your own `tidy()` function (and then maybe submit it to the maintainers of `broom`).  It's not difficult in principle.

Comment: adding to my previous comment - `wfe` does not deliver a predict method for the resulting  `wfedid` class in this case.

Comment: maybe ask the package maintainer directly - https://github.com/insongkim/wfe/issues

Comment: Thanks - I added a pastebin link for the dput(mod.did) output. Maybe this helps

Comment: (and maybe consider using a less fancy model :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a start at a `tidy` method:

```r
library(dplyr); library(tibble)

tidy.wfedid <- function(x, conf.int=FALSE, conf.level=0.95, ...) {
   cc <- (coef(summary(x))
      %>% as.data.frame()
      %>% setNames(c("estimate","std.error","statistic","p.value"))
      %>% tibble::rownames_to_column("term")
      %>% as_tibble()
   )
   return(cc)
}
```

Note that (1) I haven't implemented the confidence interval stuff (you could do this by using `mutate` to add columns `(conf.low, conf.high)` = `term` ± `std.error*qnorm((1+conf.level)/2)`; (2) this gives the standard "tidy" method, which gives a coefficient table. If you want predictions and confidence intervals on predictions you will need to write an `augment` method ...

Comment: This is great. More importantly, iIalso understood what the issue is for when this happens again. Thank you so much!

Comment: (and feel free to add it here: https://github.com/tidymodels/broom, it will probably help others)